# How to check if a JSON key exists?

Tags: java, android, json

So, I get some JSON values from the server but I don't know if there will be a particular field or not.

So like:

```
{ "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited"
}
```

And sometimes, there will be an extra field like:

```
{ "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
  "country":"Congo",
  "status":"invited",
  "club":"somevalue"
}
```

I would like to check if the field named "club" exists so that at parsing I won't get

> org.json.JSONException: No value for club

Comment: if(jsonObject.getString("club")!=null){ //get the vale here }

Comment: No, at the exception handling the code stops, and further parse actions wont run.

Comment: @SoftwareSainath Thats not works, still got the exception.

Comment: String clubvalue="";try(clubvalue=jsonobject.getString("club");}catch(Exception e){ }

Answer (score 340, accepted):

JSONObject class has a method named "has":

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

> Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

Comment: What if the key is from `Integer` type?

Comment: @Eido95 having an `Integer` as a key sounds like bad practice. JSON should be with a String key and a value of whatever you need.

Comment: @Eido95, I believe for an integer there is always a value, every time you declare an integer, you have to initialize it with a value.

Answer (score 183):

You can check this way where 'HAS' - Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

```
if (json.has("status")) {
   String status = json.getString("status"));
}

if (json.has("club")) {
   String club = json.getString("club"));
}
```

> You can also check using 'isNull' - Returns true if this object has no
>   mapping for name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.

```
if (!json.isNull("club"))
    String club = json.getString("club"));
```

Comment: which json lib are you using, can you provide a simple example for json-smart or json-simple

Comment: @samuelowino json is the variable wich contains your object

Answer (score 19):

you could `JSONObject#has`, providing the `key` as input and check if the method returns `true` or `false`. You could also

use `optString` instead of `getString`:

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if
>   necessary. Returns the empty string if no such mapping exists

Comment: Although this method of may be of use for others, this does not return if the value exists. If `getString` would have returned an empty string, `optString` would also return an empty string. Assumption would then have you believe that the property isn't available in OP's situation.

Comment: @Blackbelt do you have sources for this?

Answer (score 18):

just before read key check it like before read

```
JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject(yourjsonstr);
if(!json_obj.isNull("club"))
{
  //it's contain value to be read operation
}
else
{
  //it's not contain key club or isnull so do this operation here
}
```

isNull function definition

```
Returns true if this object has no mapping for name or
if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.
```

official documentation below link for `isNull` function

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `has`

```
public boolean has(String key)
```

Determine if the **[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)** contains a ***specific key***.

**Example**

```
JSONObject JsonObj = new JSONObject(Your_API_STRING); //JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs

if (JsonObj.has("address")) { 
    //Checking address Key Present or not
    String get_address = JsonObj .getString("address"); // Present Key
}
else {
    //Do Your Staff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A better way, instead of using a conditional like:

```
if (json.has("club")) {
    String club = json.getString("club"));
 }
```

is to simply use the existing method optString(), like this:

```
String club = json.optString("club);
```

the optString("key") method will return an empty String if the key does not exist and won't, therefore, throw you an exception.

Comment: I had no idea this existed until your answer. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Very Good Answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let json=yourJson

if(json.hasOwnProperty(yourKey)){
    value=json[yourKey]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Json has a method called `containsKey()`.

You can use it to check if a certain key is contained in the Json set.

```java
File jsonInputFile = new File("jsonFile.json"); 
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(jsonInputFile);
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);
JsonObject frameObj = reader.readObject();
reader.close();

if frameObj.containsKey("person") {
      //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(!jsonObj.isNull("club")){
    jsonObj.getString("club");
}
```

Comment: `isNull` is actually for to check if mapping is null, not for checking availability of a json member.

Answer (score 1):

```
I used hasOwnProperty('club')

var myobj = { "regatta_name":"ProbaRegatta",
    "country":"Congo",
    "status":"invited"
 };

 if ( myobj.hasOwnProperty("club"))
     // do something with club (will be false with above data)
     var data = myobj.club;
 if ( myobj.hasOwnProperty("status"))
     // do something with the status field. (will be true with above ..)
     var data = myobj.status;
```

works in all current browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to check wether the key exists or not:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonfile);
if (object.containskey("key")) {
  object.get("key");
  //etc. etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just adding another thing, In case you just want to check whether anything is created in JSONObject or not you can use **length**(), because by default when JSONObject is initialized and no key is inserted, it just has empty braces `{}` and using **has**(String key) doesn't make any sense.

So you can directly write `if (jsonObject.length() > 0)` and do your things.

Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **JsonNode#hasNonNull(String fieldName)**, it mix the **has** method and the verification if it is a **null** value or not