# String Jsonarray in android

Tags: arrays, json

I have an API POST request. but when the response came out it give 2 different response in different condition.

1st: `{"status":1,"result":{"user_key":"user_key","username":"username","verification_code_required":true}}`

2nd: `{"status":1,"result":{"user_id":"user_id","username":"username","is_authenticator":"0","authenticator_secret":"secret"}}`

Here the question. Now I want to handle different activity using IF ELSE statement. When i use

```
if(results.getBoolean("verification_code_required") ){
    }else if{results.getString("is_authenticator") == 0{ 
    }
```

It return me `error : org.json.JSONException: No value for is_authenticator`
when i get 1st response.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: please share complete code  and stack trace

Comment: I found the answer I want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17487273/9719709). Hope can help those who need it.